# spark.readstream and writestream for json issue in databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, spark-structured-streaming

I have a json

```
{
"name": "John",
"age": 30,
"car": "testing"}
```

I have a code in databricks

```
struct2 = StructType([StructField("name", StringType(), True), \
StructField("age", IntegerType(), True, None), \
                  StructField("car", StringType(), True, None)])
df2 = spark.readStream.schema(struct2).format('json') \
  .load("abfss://i**********.dfs.core.windows.net/streamjson/")
```

and the next step I start the writestream to another folder

```
df2.select("name","age","car").writeStream.format('json')\
  .option("checkpointLocation", "abfss://****@*****.dfs.core.windows.net/outputstream/jsoncheckpoint3") \
  .start("abfss://***@******.dfs.core.windows.net/streamjsonoutput/")
```

I put new files there , and I check the files in streamjsonoutput , the files are like in the following

[image]

anyone can point out what I done wrongly ?

Comment: is that only content in the file? Is it really multi-line?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `.option("multiLine", "true")` to your `spark.readStream`, because by default, Spark expects that JSON file consists of individual JSON objects per each line, not spanning multiple lines (see [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.json.html#pyspark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.json)):

```py
df2 = spark.readStream.schema(struct2).option("multiLine", "true") \
  .json("abfss://...")
```